# .append JQuery whilst declaring a variable

Tags: jquery

Basically i tried this:

```
var newDiv = $('#parentDiv').append("<div id=\""+user_name+"\" div class=\"user_head\">"+"</div>");
```

But when I try to append to the newDiv, it appends to the #parentDiv.

How can i declare a variable for the new DIV created from append?

Comment: you can change the name of parentDiv to something else and the div created to parentDiv at the end of the append

Comment: wht do you want to do here, you code itself says that you are appending a `<div>` to `#parentDiv`.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't make sense to me, please could you give a small example? thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Murtaza yes thats what I am doing... but i want to stord the newly created Div into a variable

Comment: append the div first to parent div and store the newly created div in a variable just write `var newDiv= $("#parentDiv div:last")` by this u will get the latest appended div insie the parentDiv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) and switch the order of the selectors:

```
var newDiv = $("<div id=\""+user_name+"\" div class=\"user_head\">"+"</div>").appendTo("#parentDiv")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), rather than append.

```
var newDiv = $("<div id=\""+user_name+"\" div class=\"user_head\">"+"</div>")
                   .appendTo('#parentDiv');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can cache the div you create as a jquery object, append it to something, and then reference it later.

Like this:

```
var newDiv = $('<div id="'+user_name+'"></div>');
$('#parentDiv').append(newDiv);
newDiv.append('someOtherContent');
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nKvSz/

Answer (score 0):

you have the newly created div id stored in the variable `user_name` .you can get it easily using that.

```
$('#parentDiv').append("<div id='"+user_name+"' class='user_head'>"+text+"</div>");
$('#'+user_name).append("new_div_details");
```

some small change in your code as  well.

Answer (score 0):

check this

http://jsfiddle.net/Qg5WQ/14/